# Fourier transform of $\displaystyle{f(x) = \frac{1}{(x+i)^{n}}} $

Tags: fourier-analysis, complex-integration, fourier-transform

Could anyone give me a suggestion to calculate the Fourier transform of the following function?

$f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$ defined by 
$\displaystyle{f(x) = \frac{1}{(x+i)^{n}}} $

where $n$ is a integer and $n\geqslant{2}$

Comment: Use the Calculus of Residues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**

$$F(k)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{ikx}}{x+i}\,dx=\begin{cases}0&,k>0\\\\-2\pi ie^{-|k|} &,k<0\end{cases}$$

What is $F'(k)$?  What is $F''(k)$?  What is $F^{(n)}(k)$?